# Custom Uri or endpoint on WSO2

Tags: web-services, uri, wso2, endpoint

We have just installed our WSO2 ESB, and we are trying to create some proxies services with customs endpoints.

The default endoint format is:

- http://{host}:{port}/services/{Proxy Service Name}

I'd like to have something like:

- http://{host}:{port}/services/utilities/{Proxy Service Name}
- http://{host}:{port}/services/public/{Proxy Service Name}

I followed this tutorial:

- http://wso2.org/library/knowledge-base/2011/01/custom-urls-wso2-esb-proxy-services

but we have a problem, when I send a request to my custom endpoint, I have no answer.

suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you were able to properly create a custom endpoint and "I have no answer" means you didn't get any response. If it is the case following are the possible reasons for that,

1. Proxy service endpoint didn't receive the request
2. Proxy service didn't configured properly to response back

So test whether the 1 is the reason you can simply put a log mediator with following configuration in inSequence,

<log level="full"/>

then if the proxy service received a message it will log it in console. If that works could you please post your proxy service configuration to check whether it is properly defined.

Comment: Thanks Malith, it seems to be the first option, the proxy service endpoint didn't receive the request...Do I have to apply any new configuration?

Comment: Did you try to send the request via ESB web consoles "Try this service" option, if not follow the following steps and check whether it works,                                                             GO to ESB web console> select "List" under "Services" menu in left hand side > From that list locate your custom proxy with custom url > Select "Try this service" option and send a message(just put the body)

Comment: No luck.

After apply all the configuration of the tutorial on the axis2.xml, I'm able to configurate one of my proxy services with a custom url. I've configurated it adding in "parameters" -> "/CustomURL/Part1/Part2".

If I "try the service", the response is "org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The input stream for an incoming message is null." And if I click on "Using endpoind" on the same page, I can see that the endpoint of the WS is my custom url.

I've checked also that I can not see the WSDL on the custom URL, but I can see the WSDL on the default WSDL...

Comment: I realized there is a issue with "try the service" option with custom urls. So that AxisFault is acceptable. When sending a request to the custom endpoint what url you used?                                                                 my guess is that is the point things got wrong. Lets say your proxys name is "foo", and your custom url is "/CustomURL/Part1/Part2". you should send the requsest to the "http://localhost:8280/CustomURL/Part1/Part2" not to "http://localhost:8280/CustomURL/Part1/Part2/foo".

Comment: In my case, the proxy didn't logged anything (reason 2). So what I have to do now?

Comment: @ViníciusFonseca did you solve the problem? I have a problem just like you. The proxy does not receive any thing from the custom URL

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems that we've found a solution, I'm going to resume the full solution.

As the tutorial indicates, to costumize your proxy service endpoint, you have to add the following handler on the axis2.xml configuration:

```
<handler name="CustomURIBasedDispatcher" class="org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.CustomURIBasedDispatcher"/>
```

Then, you can customize your endpoint on the design view or on the source view, I've choosen the source view, adding this parameter:

```
<parameter name="ServiceURI">/services/intern</parameter>
```

The custom endpoint is autogenerated as:

```
http://{host}:{port}/services/intern.myWebservice
```

But I has not worked for me.  If I send a request to the custom endpoint, I have no response.

I've solved the problem, adding to the "ServiceURI" parameter the name of the service:

```
<parameter name="ServiceURI">/services/intern/myWebService</parameter>
```

then you have to send the request to the following endpoint:

```
http://{host}:{port}/services/intern/myWebService
```

So now you have a custom endpoint for every proxy service.

Thanks Malith for your help.

Comment: I have tried your solution, but still getting the blank page. I didn't understand "The custom endpoint is autogenerated as...". How can I check it? My problem is explained at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19437894/custom-uri-not-working-on-wso2-esb-4-7-0. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, a few years later; I have an issue with CustomURI http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32097411/wso2-esb-custom-url